# Where is the "pere" in "ammeter"?

Tags: etymology, terminology, science, morphology, word-formation

The instrument to measure current in amperes is called *ammeter*, while the instrument to measure charge in coulombs is called *coulombmeter*.

What happened to the *-pere*? Is there a historical reason for this?

*Ampere-meter* stands for the seldom used unit A*m.

Comment: +1, intersting question, Jonas. I'm not aware of that, and it seems really strange. FWIW, French people say "‎ampèremètre" and Italian say "amperometro". I hope someone clarify this mistery.

Comment: @Jasper sorry, I upvoted this question and after I did that there were 3 votes up here. However I do not have the same perception on this "strange downvotes" phenomenon, but - on the point - I think more people should use their quota of downvotes, because they make the site better.

Comment: It would be nice, if the downvoters would leave a comment too. I have no idea how to improve now.

Comment: Another name for coulombmeter is voltameter, which sounds better IMO but could lead to confusion with voltmeter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Ampère*, named after André-Marie Ampère, is first attested in the Oxford English Dictionary in the same year, 1881, as the term was adopted by the Paris Electric Congress. *Ammeter* appears a year later. In that short time, it rather looks as if the phonetical process of elision became reflected in the word’s spelling. Elision occurs when a sound is lost by the influence of those around it, and a consonant is particularly vulnerable when three occur together. In this case, the bilabial consonant /p/ seems to have been squeezed out by the repeated bilabial consonant /m/ that would otherwise have produced *ampmeter*.

Answer (score 10):

Most likely, it's derived from the common short form of the unit, *amp* (pronounced /ˈæmp/), which is obviously derived by shortening *ampere*. Then, in speech, the /p/ gets elided from the awkward /mpm/ sequence of **ampmeter*, giving the current pronunciation.

(I don't know why the *p* was deleted in spelling, though. Perhaps it was filtered through a language like Italian that conventionally drops silent letters in spelling.)